# Migration to Spring Data Neo4J 3.3 caused neo to return old data

Tags: playframework, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, playframework-2.3

I'm running Spring Data Neo4j on two **playframework 2.3.8** servers, after migrating to the new spring data neo4j (3.3.0) have been getting different results from queries from each of the servers. This didn't happen before when i was using version 3.2.1. I am using neo4j as a server and not embedded.

My site shows a status (NORMAL or ERROR) which is changed by users. The status is updated every 2 seconds by polling one of the two servers. The problem is I have times that each server returns different results. So although the status is stable in the DB (confirmed by the neo4j console) it changes rapidly for the users every time they poll a different server.

I thought that perhaps i am getting a cached result from the server but couldn't find anything about caching in the new spring data that would explain this.

I've noticed that this problem happens when I use the repository findOne function and when i switched to using a new function with a query (`@query("match n where id(n) = {0} return n")`) it stopped happening. It happens in a few other places including when i use `template.fetch(o)`. it may happen also in other places that i'm not aware of.

Comment: Hmm weird, can you narrow that down? Are oyu using Neo4j embedded or as server?

Comment: Using it as a server

Comment: Can you create an example project that exhibits the issues?

Comment: Would take some time... I'm currently working on a separate secure network with no access to the outer world... do you perhaps have any idea what could cause this type of thing... maybe a caching feature I can shut off?

Comment: Working on an app that shows the problem, might take a while... any suggestions meanwhile? this is supposed to go to production in a few days :(

Comment: then use the @query function, which is what find one uses internally too

Comment: Problem is I am doing template.fetch to lazy load related nodes l and there I cant do @query

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand this issue well enough without a small code example that reproduces it.

Comment: Still trying to recreate... I noticed I forgot to mention in the question that I am runing this on a play framework server. The problem may be from the playside although I havent changed a play version before this started happening

Comment: I think this may be do to this open issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/235#thread-subscription-status